# Integer overflow before add, but not after?

Tags: assembly, masm

I have two variables that I ask user for input:

```
number_1    DWORD   ?
number_2    DWORD   ?
sum         DWORD   ?
```

From what I understand, a DWORD is an unsigned 32-bit integer data that can store integers from 0 through 4,294,967,295.

However, when I input 2,147,483,648, or 1 more than the signed integer range, using code below:

```
call    readInt
mov     number_1, eax
```

I receive a `<32-bit integer overflow>` warning in the command prompt.

However, I can input 2,147,483,647 into both `number_1` and `number_2`, `add` them and store in `sum` without problem. And when displayed it show 4,294,967,294, as it's supposed to.

Is the EAX register only able to accept up to the max value of a signed 32-bit integer?

Comment: `eax` can hold 32 bits, regardless of whether the data is considered signed or unsigned. I'm not sure why this happens.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "input", how are you "receiving" a warning, and what's the exact message?

Comment: Updated to include input code and the exact warning received.

Comment: What is `readInt`?

Comment: It must be a function in Kip Irvine's (our textbook author) library that we've been using - didn't realize it wasn't an actual assembly language function. That's probably where the error has been happening.

Comment: I'm not sure what an "*actual assembly language function*" would be. Assembly doesn't have built-in functions. Everything you can `call` is implemented somewhere else.

Comment: I meant it must be a function the author created himself, rather than a standard MASM syntax.

Comment: Indeed. I found the following in `Irvine32.inc`: "*ReadInt PROTO  ; read signed decimal integer from console*". Looks like it's designed to read signed integers.

Comment: In assembly there are no functions, all the instructions are defined in instruction reference guide. And yes, eax is 32 bits (you can put there anything you wish, as long as it's 32 bits, for example two 16b numbers with interleaved bits ... will be difficult to use, and it's probably not good for anything, but you *can*). So all this "read int", and singed/unsigned is in your code, not in CPU or Assembly. (for you it is "library" code, not yours, but from the point of build/debug/maintenance it is "your" code, which gets included in the executable.. without it there is no "ReadInt" available)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `EAX` register can accept any value that can be expressed using 32 bits.

When you got the "32-bit integer overflow" warning it was **the programmer who wrote** the *readInt* library function that decided values should be considerd signed quantities. Ranging from [-2GB,+2GB-1]. He checked it and flagged the error.

When you yourself write the following code:

```
mov  eax, 2147483647
mov  ebx, 2147483647
add  eax, ebx
```

it is **entirely up to you** to make this same decision.

To the processor that has to execute the `add eax, ebx` instruction it doesn't matter. The result 4294967294 snuggly fits in the available 32 bits. Even if the true sum were bigger than 4294967295, the CPU will - without complaining - put the lowest 32 bits of the result in the `EAX` register and the 33th bit in the carry flag.